# ページ読み込み時にタブ切り替え

Tags: javascript, jquery

回答ありがとうございます。

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.tabs > .c').trigger('click');
});

$(function(){
 // タブをクリック時
 $('.tabs > div').click(function(){
  $('.tabs > div,.tab_content').removeClass('active');

  var tabClass = $(this).attr('class');

  $(this).addClass('active');

  $('.tab_content').each(function(){
      // indexOfだと、'a', 'b', 'c'の場合に常にtrueとなるため、classの最後のみ比較するように修正
   //if($(this).attr('class').indexOf(tabClass) != -1){
      if($(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1] === tabClass){
    $(this).addClass('active').fadeIn();

   }else{
    $(this).hide();
   }
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tabs">
 <div class="a">タブ1</div>
 <div class="b">タブ2</div>
 <div class="c">タブ3</div>
 <div class="d">タブ4</div>
</div>

<div class="tab_content a active">
 <p>aaaaa</p>
</div>

<div class="tab_content b">
 <p>bbbbb</p>
</div>

<div class="tab_content c">
 <p>ccccc</p>
</div>

<div class="tab_content d">
 <p>ddddd</p>
</div>
```

上記教えていただいた通り実行しますと読み込み時、全てのtab_contentが表示されております。
ご教授願いいたします^^;

Comment: 質問の更新にともない、回答も更新しました。ご確認ください。

Comment: 更新いただきました回答で解決いたしました!ありがとうございます。タブ設定時にイベント発行がわかっておりませんでした^^;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabs > .c').trigger('click');
});
```

と以下は同じ意味になります。

```
$(function() {
  $('.tabs > .c').trigger('click');
});
```

また、ページ読み込み時に`click`するためには、`click`前にタブにイベントハンドラが設定されている必要があります。

そのため、以下のようにタブのイベントハンドラ設定後に、同じ`$(function(){`内でイベント発行すれば良いと思います。

```
$(function(){
    // タブをクリック時のイベントハンドラ設定
    // ...省略...

  // タブのクリックイベントを発行
  $('.tabs > .c').trigger('click');
});
```

以下は、初回に'c'タブをクリックする場合の例になります。

```js
$(function(){
 // タブをクリック時のイベントハンドラ設定
 $('.tabs > div').click(function(){
  $('.tabs > div,.tab_content').removeClass('active');

  var tabClass = $(this).attr('class');

  $(this).addClass('active');

  $('.tab_content').each(function(){
      // indexOfだと、'a', 'b', 'c'の場合に常にtrueとなるため、classの最後のみ比較するように修正
   //if($(this).attr('class').indexOf(tabClass) != -1){
      if($(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1] === tabClass){
    $(this).addClass('active').fadeIn();

   }else{
    $(this).hide();
   }
  });
 });
  
  // タブのクリックイベントを発行
  $('.tabs > .c').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
.tabs > div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

.tabs > .active {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tabs">
 <div class="a">タブ1</div>
 <div class="b">タブ2</div>
 <div class="c">タブ3</div>
 <div class="d">タブ4</div>
</div>

<div class="tab_content a active">
 <p>aaaaa</p>
</div>

<div class="tab_content b">
 <p>bbbbb</p>
</div>

<div class="tab_content c">
 <p>ccccc</p>
</div>

<div class="tab_content d">
 <p>ddddd</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

回答ありがとうございます。
下記のコードに変更して見ました。

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.tabs > .c').trigger('click');
});

$(function(){
 // タブをクリック時
 $('.tabs > div').click(function(){
  $('.tabs > div,.tab_content').removeClass('active');

  var tabClass = $(this).attr('class');

  $(this).addClass('active');

  $('.tab_content').each(function(){

   if($(this).attr('class').indexOf(tabClass) != -1){

    $(this).addClass('active').fadeIn();

   }else{
    $(this).hide();
   }
  });
 });
});
```

再度ご教授願いできますでしょうか？

Comment: 回答者は質問を見ますので、回答を追加するのではなく、質問のスニペットを編集していただいた方が良いです。修正よろしくお願いします。